# How to collapse ImageView nested inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have the following layout

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <CardView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <ImageView />
            <View />
        </LinearLayout>
    </CardView>

    <RecyclerView />

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I just want to hide the ImageView with parallax animation whenever the RecyclerView is scrolled down and show the ImageView whenever RecyclerView is scrolled up. I got to know that this behaviour can be achieved using CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 1):

For a parallax effect you need to use **AppBarLayout** and **CollapsingToolbarLayout**.
You can try putting **ImageView** with attribute

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout above the **Toolbar**

Detailed code with CoordinatorLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:statusBarBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.android">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDarkTransparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="208dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image_you_want"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDarkTransparent2"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppBarTitleappearance"
            app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/AppBarSubtitleApppearanceLight"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/ornage"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Make sure you have following namespaces in your root tag of the layout

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

As per your requirement you can Use any layout at that position with attribute

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

I hope you will get some help from this.

Answer (score 0):

The view you do want to collapse must be wrapped within `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`.
 
Try the structure below:

```
<....CoordinatorLayout
    ....
    ... 
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <!-- Your collapsing content will goes here -->

           </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <...NestedScrollView
         ..... 
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</....CoordinatorLayout>
```